# Facebook Javascript SDK - Query Profile Picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm trying to query the Profile picture via the Javascript SDK.

I do **not want the graph api link**, I want to get the `src_big` link.

I have following code:

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "id,name,picture"}, function(response)
{

    alert( response.picture );


    FB.api(
            {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT pid, src_big, src_big_height, src_big_width FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="' + response.id + '" AND name = "Profile Pictures")'
            },
            function(data1) {

                alert('BIG ' + data1.pic_big );

            }
    );


});
```

It should give me the `src_big` but it does not.
Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not while querying it, the problem was while accessing the object.

It has to be accessed in a weird way.

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "id,name,picture"}, function(response)
{

    FB.api(
            {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT pid, src_big, src_big_height, src_big_width FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="' + response.id + '" AND name = "Profile Pictures")'
            },
            function(data1) {
                alert( data1[0].src_big );
            }
    );

});
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to break the string to add the user id. You can use the `me()` method: `'SELECT pid,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me() AND name = "Profile Pictures")'`

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, couldn't get it to work but this did:

You can get specific sizes of the profile pic as well.

```
FB.api("/me/picture?width=180&height=180",  function(response) {

        console.log(response.data.url);

});
```

See the [Facebook documentation to see what different picture sizes you can get](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/).

And my demo with login at: [Get Facebook Profile Picture with Javascript SDK](http://www.jensbits.com/2013/04/04/get-facebook-profile-picture-with-javascript-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get profile picture from user table of the fql.

The query would be

```
"select uid, pic, pic_small, pic_big, pic_square from user where uid=me()"
//replace this me() with the id of the user
```

This will return all the link for the profile pictures.

What you are trying is to get from the albums of the user...