# facebook registration plugin - get either large profile pic or username or userid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using facebook registration plugin. I can get the profile pic of the user by knowing either his facebook username or userid (accesstoken not required for pic). I can get userid or username by getting the access token etc. But , i cant get the username or userid from accesstoken here. So, is there any way i can get the username or userid or large profile pic from registration plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Javascript SDK, you can use Javascript to get the profile picture by doing this:

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "id,name,picture"}, function(response){
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="' + response.id + '" AND name = "Profile Pictures")'
        },
        function(data) {
            alert( data[0].src_big ); // this will alert the URL of the profile picture (stored in data[0].src_big), replace the alert with some useful operation
        }
    );
});
```

See similar post: [Facebook Javascript SDK - Query Profile Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468325/facebook-javascript-sdk-query-profile-picture)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work for me but this did:

You can get specific sizes of the profile pic as well.

```
FB.api("/me/picture?width=180&height=180",  function(response) {

        console.log(response.data.url);

});
```

See the [Facebook documentation to see what different picture sizes you can get](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/).

And a complete demo with login at: [Get Facebook Profile Picture with Javascript SDK](http://www.jensbits.com/2013/04/04/get-facebook-profile-picture-with-javascript-sdk/)